# "to take his chances in the boat"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I ran into these sentences in the dictionary, and I know the meaning of "take one's chances". But I can't put together the whole meaning of the sentences. What do they mean?

1. "He decided to **take his chances in the boat**."
2. "He was **tak**ing **a chance on** **a** relatively new young **actor**."

Comment: Ask only one question. I've removed the first one about " the comittee consists" as it doesn't relate to the title. You can raise a new question if you wish.

Comment: You say "I know the meaning of 'take one's chances".  Can you explain what you understand the meaning to be?

Comment: Hello.  I suggest you visit our [help] and read [ask]  One principle is "one post, one question"  so we get a library of questions and answers for everybody, not just you.  Another is "search and research", which you have done.  If you tell us what you understand the meaning to be then we can write a better answer. Perhaps your understanding is correct.  Perhaps it is wrong but if you don't tell us, then how can we tell?  Remember that we just do this for fun. Nobody is getting paid.  It's up to you to make this as easy as you can for us.

Comment: @mystery: Don't get too uptight! You probably don't realise that for most long-term users of Stack Exchange sites, the primary purpose is to build a searchable repository of questions with "validated" answers, which isn't *always* 100% compatible with the goal ***you*** seek (whereby our primary purpose would be to give the questioner the information he seeks as quickly and efficiently as possible).

Comment: @JamesK It's better to close the question as "needs more focus" and let the author decide which of their questions they want to ask than to arbitrarily remove one of them. Closing the question will prevent others from spending time answering parts of the question that may change when it is brought on-topic.

Comment: Don't vandalize your question. If you don't want to ask it, you should delete it. You should be able to, because the only answer to it was deleted. [This page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) in the [help] has more information.

Comment: take a chance on = take chances on, same thing.

Comment: @ColleenV,  Voting to close a couple of perfectly reasonable questions that only needed splitting in two seems a bit harsh.  It's better to fix questions when they can be fixed and only close those that can't be fixed.

Comment: @JamesK Closing is not permanent. It’s intended to put a hold on answers and give the author time to fix the question. Once it’s in a better form it can be reopened. It’s not punitive. It’s certainly not worse than someone arbitrarily deciding for the author which of their two questions is the one that should be answered.

Comment: That is indeed the intention but we all know that it doesn't work that way.  reopening is hard. Usually closed questions go nowhere. Closing a question is the kiss of death. Editing a question  (and not arbitarily:  there was one question in the title, that is the main question) fixes it, makes it more useful.  We are encouraged to edit if possible. It was possible.  Plenty more people get put off by their question being closed than being edited.  However this was just an impatient OP who wanted answers **now** and started insulting people when they didn't get them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer the original question, which is the second one.

By "taking a chance", it could mean that the person or people are willing to take the risk in any condition whatsoever.

The sentence:

> He decided to take his chances in the boat.

The situation could be that the man is on some problem in that body of water, and decides to take the risk to get through the situation.

The other sentence:

> He was taking a chance on a relatively new young actor.

Not sure who the "he" might be referring to, but the "he" is willing to take a risk on getting this specific actor to do something.